# How do I stop my code from executing until an asynchronous piece of code has completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Today I've been struggling to get some JavaScript code working.

The goal of this code is to have all of the files names returned by the ajax function calls populated within the `fileNameObj` before the `recordFormSubmission` function is called.

```
async function uploadSubmissionFiles(files)
{
    //Get an array for the names of each key of the files object
    var filesKeys = Object.keys(files);
    var fileSubmissionErrors = [];
    var formElementPK = "";

    //Create an object that keeps track of the file names that are saved to the server
    var fileNamesObj = {};

    //For each question where we uploaded files, call an ajax function 
    //where we transfer the files from the client to the server
    var promiseToUploadFiles = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => 
        {
            for(let i = 0; i < filesKeys.length; i++)
            {
                formElementPK = filesKeys[i].match("(?<=fpk).*");
                console.log(formElementPK);
                if(files[filesKeys[i]]["type"] == "canvas")
                {
                    var canvasElement = files[filesKeys[i]]["response"];
                    var canvasImageBase64 = canvasElement.toDataURL().split(';base64,')[1];
                    //Use ajax to upload the file to the server
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: "./includes/ajaxColdfusion/fillout/submittedFileUpload.cfc?method=uploadSubmittedCanvasImage",
                            type: "POST", 
                            data: canvasImageBase64,
                            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                            contentType: false,
                            processData: false
                        }
                    )
                    .then( function(response)
                        {
                            var responseElements = response.getElementsByTagName("string");
                            var resultMessage = responseElements[0].innerHTML;
                            console.log("File upload result for " + canvasElement.id + ": " + resultMessage);

                            if(resultMessage == "success")
                            {
                                //On success, responseElements[1] contains the name of the file that was saved to the server. We record it!
                                fileNamesObj[formElementPK] = responseElements[1].innerHTML;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //On failure, responseElements[1] contains the error message for what happened during the upload
                                fileSubmissionErrors.push(responseElements[1].innerHTML);
                                fileNamesObj[formElementPK] = "error.png";
                            }
                            console.log(fileNamesObj);
                        }
                    );
                }
                else if(files[filesKeys[i]]["type"] == "fileUpload")
                {
                    var fileUploadForm = files[filesKeys[i]]["response"];
                    var formData = new FormData(fileUploadForm);
                    var fileFieldName = document.getElementById("question" + formElementPK + "FileUpload").getAttribute("name");
                    formData.append("fileFieldName", fileFieldName);
                    //Use ajax to upload the file to the server
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: "./includes/ajaxColdfusion/fillout/submittedFileUpload.cfc?method=uploadSubmittedFile",
                            type: "POST", 
                            data: formData,
                            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                            contentType: false,
                            processData: false
                        }
                    )
                    .then( function(response)
                        {
                            var responseElements = response.getElementsByTagName("string");
                            var resultMessage = responseElements[0].innerHTML;
                            console.log("File upload result for " + fileUploadForm.id + ": " + resultMessage);

                            if(resultMessage == "success")
                            {
                                //On success, responseElements[1] contains the name of the file that was saved to the server. We record it!
                                fileNamesObj[formElementPK] = responseElements[1].innerHTML;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //On failure, responseElements[1] contains the error message for what happened during the upload
                                fileSubmissionErrors.push(responseElements[1].innerHTML);
                                fileNamesObj[formElementPK] = "error.png";   
                            }
                            console.log(fileNamesObj);
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
            
            var retObj = {
            "fileSubmissionErrors" : fileSubmissionErrors,
            "fileNames" : fileNamesObj
            }
            console.log("Resolved the promise!");
            resolve(retObj);
        });
    }
    
    return await promiseToUploadFiles();
}


async function recordFormSubmission(data, formPK, fileNames)
{
    var JSONData = JSON.stringify(data);
    var JSONFileNames = JSON.stringify(fileNames);
    var submissionErrors = [];

    console.log("Filenames at trigger of record form submission: ", fileNames);
    console.log("Now waiting 2 seconds with     await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));");
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
    console.log("Fileanmes after 2 seconds of triggering record form submission", fileNames);

    $.ajax(
        {
            url: "./includes/ajaxColdfusion/fillout/recordFormSubmission.cfc?method=recordFormSubmission",
            type: "POST", 
            data: "JSONData=" + JSONData + "&formPK=" + formPK + "&JSONFileNames=" + JSONFileNames,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            cache : false
        }
    ).
    done(function(response)
        {
            //If successful...
            console.log("Record form submission successful:" + response.getElementsByTagName("string")[0].innerHTML);
        }
    ).
    fail(function(response)
        { 
            //If not successful...
            console.log("Record form submission failed");
            submissionErrors = [response.getElementsByTagName("string")[1]];
        }
    );

    return submissionErrors;
}


uploadSubmissionFiles(filesToUpload.then( function(fromUploadSubmissionFiles)
{
     var fileSubmissionErrors = 
     fromUploadSubmissionFiles["fileSubmissionErrors"]
     var fileNames = fromUploadSubmissionFiles["fileNames"];
     //Query the database to save our form data to the database
     var formDataSubmissionErrors = recordFormSubmission(dataToRecord, formPK, fileNames);
}
```

Above are all the important parts of this code. As it stands right now though, recordFormSubmission() gets called and executes before the fileNamesObj variable is populated with file names that are returned from the ajax function. This must mean that the code is not waiting on the ajax to finish executing before continuing with execution, even though a promise has been implemented.

I suppose my question here is, what am I doing wrong if I want the JavaScript code to wait until all of the ajax functions are completed before calling `recordFormSubmission()`?

I could probably think of a polling solution here, but I'd like to think that there's a way to solve this with promises or better practice.

This is the result of running the modified code to return an awaited promise. It also shows how the ajax functions return and the filenames are obtained in the window of time between waiting two seconds and when the critical point where the filenames must exist occurs.
[image: C]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [blocking javascript execution until response is completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822215/blocking-javascript-execution-until-response-is-completed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was found within an answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66747114/16511184

Credit to @Heretic-Monkey for providing it.

The solution: put an `await` in front of each `ajax()` function call. Do NOT encapsulate anything within a promise.

I'm new to the concept of Promises in Javascript, so I unknowingly made an error of encapsulating promises inside of eachother. It's very important to note that the jquery `ajax()` function returns a promise. In my problem, I was triggering asynchronous code that I was not using `await` for. Instead I used `await` for a function that contained an `ajax()` function. The `await` wouldn't wait very long at all because all the code was doing was triggering the `ajax()` function and leaving, not waiting for it to finish (the very crux of what I wanted to occur).

Here's a good analogy:

You're going to the supermarket with your friend. You tell your friend to split up from you and grab a carton of eggs. You wait for them, and once they come back from grabbing the eggs you'll both go to the checkout counter together.

Effectively, the problem I had was I decided to wait until I was done telling my friend to get eggs to go to the checkout counter. I needed to wait for my friend to SPECIFICALLY get the eggs.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
async function uploadSubmissionFiles(files)
{
     ...
     var promiseToUploadFiles = () => {
         return new Promise((resolve,reject) => 
             {
                  $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: "./includes/ajaxColdfusion/fillout/submittedFileUpload.cfc?method=uploadSubmittedFile",
                            type: "POST", 
                            data: formData,
                            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                            contentType: false,
                            processData: false
                        }
                    )
                    .then( function(response)
                        {
                            var responseElements = response.getElementsByTagName("string");
                            var resultMessage = responseElements[0].innerHTML;
                            console.log("File upload result for " + fileUploadForm.id + ": " + resultMessage);

                            if(resultMessage == "success")
                            {
                                //On success, responseElements[1] contains the name of the file that was saved to the server. We record it!
                                fileNamesObj[formElementPK] = responseElements[1].innerHTML;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //On failure, responseElements[1] contains the error message for what happened during the upload
                                fileSubmissionErrors.push(responseElements[1].innerHTML);
                                fileNamesObj[formElementPK] = "error.png";   
                            }
                            resolve(fileNamesObj);
                        }
                    )
                    .catch(function(e) {
                        reject(e)
                    });
             }
        }
    return await promiseToUploadFiles();
     ...
}

await uploadSubmissionFiles(filesToUpload).then( function(fileNameObj)
    {
        recordFormSubmission(..., fileNameObj)
    }).catch(function(e) {
        console.error(e);
    });
```

It is necessary to wrap your promise in a function and wait for its completion after the call. When you have assigned a promise to a simple variable, the request immediately starts working and the code runs on without waiting for completion

Comment: I tried this solution but changed the last line to `return promiseToUploadFiles()`. Once this promise is returned, I sent the `fileNamesObj` variable off to the `recordFormSubmission()` function where it logs to the console and still shows there are no file names populated within the object. 

It's my belief that the code is still not stopping and waiting for everything to finish, as if I just drop `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));` right before I log the the fileNamesObj to the console, the file names do appear. So I'm curious what might be the problem here.

Comment: change `return promiseToUploadFiles()` to `return await promiseToUploadFiles()`

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write that initially. I have it set to `return await promiseToUploadFiles()`.

Comment: and your `fileNamesObj`  is empty?

Comment: It is empty. In an edit to the original question, I have a small screenshot of my console upon firing the functions. You can see the file uploads finish after the code reaches the `recordFormSubmission()` critical point where at least one file name must exist in the fileNamesObj.

Comment: please, update your code and console.log() and where setTimeout work

Comment: I realized what else is the problem. You did not return values from the promise. I have updated the answer. And if you have a global variable fileNamesObj, then in general you can not return it, but simply return true conditionally, but then in the uploadSubmissionFiles function in then you do not need to access the transmitted data, but look at the global variable

Comment: I have edited the question to contain the unabridged version of the two functions in question. I apologize for the length!

Comment: Looks like the [explicit promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/215552) is alive and well...

Comment: Thanks for this link! I believe I solved the issue with its content. I will add the answer in a sec and credit you for the link!